# Using itertools in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am importing a csv file in which the data looks like

```
25
34
45
23
34
23
24

    import itertools
    import pandas as pd
    filename = 'myFile.csv'
    myArray1 = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)

    myArray2 = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)


    for a, b  in itertools.product(myArray1, myArray2):
        print(a,b)
```

but it only output

```
0 0
```

When I run:

```
myArray1 = [2,3,4]
myArray2 = [4,5,6]
for a, b  in itertools.product(myArray1, myArray2):
    print(a,b)
```

The output is like

```
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
4 4
4 5
4 6
```

So I want the output from CSV data like this

Comment: This is going to be difficult to diagnose without more CSV data. What is the output of `myArray1` and `myArray2` before `itertools.product`?

Comment: Sorry, but you have edited your question with a different problem. You have effectively changed your problem statement. If you have a different question, please close this question, accept an answer, and open a new question. I've rolled back your edit, it will confuse readers. Please refrain from doing this again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that iteration over a dataframe by default happens over its column labels. In your case, there is only one column labelled `0` in each dataframe, so you end up getting a single output `(0, 0)`.

As a solution, you'll need to extract those values, and *then* pass it to `product`. For efficiency, do this only once.

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None).iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()
for a, b in itertools.product(data, data):
    print(a, b)
```